Content Security Policy in nextjs not loading the Nextjs script files
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request:any) {
  const nonce = Buffer.from(crypto.randomUUID()).toString("base64");
  const cspHeader = `
  script-src 'self' http://* 'nonce-${nonce}';
   default-src 'self' http://* 'nonce-${nonce}';
`;

  const contentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue = cspHeader
    .replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ")
    .trim();

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(request.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("x-nonce", nonce);
  requestHeaders.set(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    contentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue,
  );

  const response = NextResponse.next({
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
  response.headers.set(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    contentSecurityPolicyHeaderValue,
  );

  return response;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    {
      source: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)",
      missing: [
        { type: "header", key: "next-router-prefetch" },
        { type: "header", key: "purpose", value: "prefetch" },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

The middleware above is used for implementing the Content Security Policy, and it is based on the official Next.js documentation.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy
But when the application runs none of the script runs due to CSP. Below are the error shown

admin:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' http://* 'nonce-NTZlNDIzOGEtZDA2Yy00MDJhLTlhYmItNmFkNmVjNWZhZWM1'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-zlqnbDt84zf1iSefLU/ImC54isoprH/MRiVZGskwexk='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' http://* 'nonce-NTZlNDIzOGEtZDA2Yy00MDJhLTlhYmItNmFkNmVjNWZhZWM1'"

Additionally, when I inspect the page in the browser, I notice that the 'nonce' is not being properly attached to the script tag and it is empty
<script nonce="">self.__next_f.push([1,"1:HL[\"/_next/static/media/a34f9d1faa5f3315-s.p.woff2\",\"font\",{\"crossOrigin\":\"\",\"type\":\"font/woff2\"}]\n2:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1730890705581\",\"style\"]\n3:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/admin/layout.css?v=1730890705581\",\"style\"]\n4:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/admin/page.css?v=1730890705581\",\"style\"]\n0:D{\"name\":\"rQ\",\"env\":\"Server\"}\n"])</script>

I want to load all the scripts and styles from self domain.
